# Can you intentionally throw away large sums of money through transaction fees on the stock market?

Tags: trading, fees, divorce

On another thread, there was a question about a divorcee who lost tons of money day trading just before the divorce, with the result that the ex-wife received a lot less money.

Question: If you had say a million dollar, and you want to destroy it on the stock market, could you just make lots and lots of trades and lose all your money in a short time through fees?

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible or if it's legally allowed?

Comment: Sure, why would you want to? Would you burn money just to keep your ex from getting half of it (knowing you'd lose the other half). Why not just give it to charity?

Comment: @DStanley They might force the charity to give it back, if the charity still had it. They'd never force trade counterparties to give it back, not in a million years. You could, of course, also try buying bitcoins and sending them to some-address-that-nobody-knows-whose-it-is

Comment: I guess I just don't get the premise. I get that people can be petty but this seems extreme. Maybe the loss wasn't intentional and the ex-wife was just bitter? If the question is can you lose a lot of money quickly the answer is most definitely yes. Go to the nearest casino.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the other thread?

Comment: If you want to throw away money, you could always send it to me.

Comment: In the US, we have free equity trading and very low option commissions.  If you want to burn through the money, buy loads of deep out-of-the-money options that will expire shortly.  The idea of blowing the communal money is nonsensical because you're losing your money as well (1/2 the assets).

Comment: "On another thread ..." — Which thread?

Answer (score 5):

Intentionally causing loss to the communal funds in a divorce to reduce the proceeds to the ex may not be seen kindly by the courts. This is a legal question. What you're describing is called "breach of fiduciary duty".

Causing intentional damage to the marital funds us a breach of trust between the marital partners, and you may be hold liable for damages. I.e.: if in the divorce you need to split $1M, but you intentionally wasted it all on frivolous investments during the divorce process, the court may hold you liable to your ex for the whole amount even if you no longer have it.

[Example article](https://fkkblaw.com/family-law/property-division/breach-of-fiduciary-duty/) explaining this issue for the US California divorces (but it's similar almost everywhere).

Answer (score 0):

It would take an incredible number of trades for fees/commissions to wear down an account.

The fastest way to deplete a brokerage account would be with derivatives. For example, SPY has options expiring 3 days a week, you could spend the entire account on out of the money options for the next expiration and potentially lose it all.

Some people facing divorce might be inclined to make such a gamble not to intentionally destroy money, but in hopes of winning enough that splitting assets is less painful. If they lose it all then the fact that the ex gets less too might be some sort of consolation. It doesn't make great sense in any case.

I would imagine that such action could be considered in divorce proceedings and may result in unfavorable outcomes (especially if there was evidence that the person did it intentionally to avoid having to split marital assets).

Comment: In my local jurisdiction (UK), deliberately losing or getting rid of money or property ahead of some kind of assessment of means can be classed as 'wilful divestment', and the subject of the assessment can be deemed to still owe the sum they would have been required to pay, absent the divestment. This could financially cripple someone for decades, or for life.